Embedding a Product of Symmetric Groups in a Minimal Symmetric Group
Cayley's Theorem says that any finite group can be embedded in a symmetric group $ S_m $, but it says nothing about the minimum such $m$ for which this is the case. If a finite group is a direct product of non-trivial symmetric groups then it's quite easy to see that $m$ is bounded by the sum of their indexes. Is this the minimal possible $m$? In other words:

Let $k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_t$ be positive integers greater than $1$ and $n = k_1 + \cdots + k_t$. What is the minimum positive integer $m$ for which there exists an injection $S_{k_1} \times \cdots \times S_{k_t} \to S_m$? Is it always $m = n$?

Idea: I tried looking at the case where $n$ is prime to ensure that $(n-1)!$ is always divisible by $ {k_1 !} \cdots {k_t !} $, but this doesn't really fix anything else.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Haran has answered your question but, denoting the minimal degree of a faithful permutation representation of $G$ by $m(G)$, we always have $m(G \times H) \le m(G)+m(H)$, but we do not always have equality, and there is apparently no precise characterization of the groups for which we get equality. It's been proved in a lot of special cases, such as (almost) simple groups and nilpotent groups.

Yes, the best you can do is $m = n$. First, observe that if we have a counterexample, then we have a counterexample where all the $k_i$'s are equal to $2$ or $3$ (by replacing each $k_i > 3$ with an appropriate number of $2$'s and $3$'s whose sum is $k_i$). Let the number of $k_i$'s equal to $2$ and $3$ be equal to $r$ and $s$ respectively. The question has now been reduced to asking whether there exists an injection of the form $S_2^r \times S_3^s \to S_m$ for some $m, r, s$ with $m < 2r + 3s$. We will prove the stronger claim that for any $m, r, s$ with $m < 2r + 3s$, there does not exist an injection of the form $C_2^r \times C_3^s \to S_m$ (where $C_k$ is the cyclic group of order $k$).
Assume such an embedding exists: let $\tau_1, \ldots, \tau_r$ and $\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_s$ denote the images of the generators of $C_2^r$ and $C_3^s$ respectively and let $H$ denote the subgroup generated by them. Consider the natural action of $S_m$ on an $m$-element set $X$. Fix some $x \in X$ and look  at the $H$-orbit of $x$. We can change our generators of $H$ appropriately (using Smith Normal Form) so that the stabilizer $H' = \mathrm{Stab}_H(x)$ is generated by $\tau_{u+1}, \ldots, \tau_r$ and $\sigma_{v+1}, \ldots, \sigma_s$, where $u \leqslant r$ and $v \leqslant s$ are non-negative integers.
Now, the subgroup $H' \cong C_2^{r-u} \times C_3^{s-v}$ fixes not only $x$ but its whole orbit $\mathcal{O}$ (since $H$ is abelian). It follows that $H'$ acts faithfully on $X - \mathcal{O}$, giving us an injection $C_2^{r-u} \times C_3^{s-v} \to S_{m'}$, where $m' = m-2^u3^v$. I claim that this is a smaller counterexample. Indeed, we already know that $2r + 3s > m$, so it suffices to prove that $2u + 3v \leqslant 2^u3^v$, which I leave as an exercise for the reader. We are left with a contradiction via infinite descent.
Remark: This reminds me of the classic problem of maximizing the product of positive integers under the constraint that their sum is some fixed $n$.

Thank you!
I'm slightly confused on why H' fixing Orbit(x) implies that H' would act faithfully on the set without that orbit.

Remember that $H$ is a permutation group on $X$, and so is $H'$. Of course, if $H'$ fixes $\mathcal{O}$ as well, then it is a permutation group on $X - \mathcal{O}$, because you are just throwing away some points which are never involved in the action.
